# Ajax Call Sometimes Works, Sometime works and refreshes, Sometimes refreshes and fails …?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Currently I got this code:

```
function post_positive(id) {
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("post"+id).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","post_review.php?id="+id+"&type=positive",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
  return false; 
}
```

For my ajax call I just the function `post_positive()`. Sometimes it shows the result, sometimes with page refresh, sometimes nothing.

Comment: Which browser are you seeing this behaviour in?

Comment: Things that are wrong with this: 1) *Please* indent your code properly, it makes it *much* easier to debug 2) missing a `;` at the end of the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = ` declaration - declaring functions this way is an assignment **statement** and as such needs a semi-colon at the end of it 3) you should escape `id` before using it in a URL (with, for example, `escapeURIComponent()`). Other than those three things, there is no reason why this should not work as expected - depending on the `"post"+id` element existing, and what `post_review.php` actually does.

Comment: To addition to DaveRandom's answer please check if the post_review.php always returns a response (doesn't matter what format: text,json,xml etc), because there were multiple times where I was getting 500 errors due to an empty response from the script and that's what caused the AJAX to fail.

Comment: i missed that ; but still its showing those weird things with slow connection and @Ignas post_review.php always sends data
and i'm using chrome and mozilla both shows the same output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use jQuery ajax() method for ajax it is easy to understand and working properly
function post_positive(id){ 
$.ajax({
           type:'get',
           url:'post_review.php',
           data:{ 'id':id,'type':'positive' },
           success:function(result){
                      $("#post"+id).text(result);

}

});
}